# CNN Model to Count the Number of Occurrence of a Character in an Input

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network

How can I count the number of occurrence of a character in an input number using CNN?

Background: I am trying to predict the number of syllables in a word. A good rule of thumb is to count the number of vowels (aeiouy) in the words, this could give a correct prediction half the time. There are other more complicated rules to get a better prediction but I'd like to start with this.

Before training, I converted each alphabet that isn't a vowel i.e. a consonant to '1' and all vowels to 2.

Therefore, Apple will be converted to 21112. Then I added zeros so all inputs will be of equal size (15 characters), i.e Apple will be 211120000000000 and vehicle will be 121211200000000.

The number of classes are 1-9. 9 is the highest syllable on the dataset. The task is to count the number of 2s in the input.

The dataset was downloaded from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1moS1tkh_AJafpcIFpktaSvZwrzv5d4ix/view
The thing is, the model has refused to learn which is odd. It's stuck in 10%.

```
def create_model():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Embedding(
          input_dim=24,
          input_shape=(24,),
          input_length=len(xtrain_dataset),
          output_dim=100,
          # Use masking to handle the variable sequence lengths
          mask_zero=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
  ])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss='mse',
            metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model

#Create a basic model instance
model = create_model()
# Display the model's architecture
model.summary()

checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                             save_weights_only=True,
                                             verbose=1)

model.fit(x=xtrain_dataset,
      y=ytrain_dataset,
      epochs=50,
      batch_size=500,
      callbacks=[cp_callback]) 

os.listdir(checkpoint_dir)

def predict_syllable(w, train=train_dataset, model=model):
    pred = model.predict([w])
    return train_dataset.Syllables[pred[0]]
```

Comment: why do you need a neural network for this? why don't you just count the number of vowels?

Comment: yeah i've done that already but looking to see if I can increase the accuracy with neural network

Comment: "counting number of occurrences of a character in  an input number" does not require a neural network. you can do it with 100 % accuracy without a neural network.

Comment: I know, the goal is for the model to detect the number of syllables in the word, counting the number of vowels is the simplest method to do this. There are others but I need to get this right first then move to more complicated methods of syllabification

Comment: if I can train the model to detect the vowel patterns then I can make it detect other patterns to increase the syllabification accuracy

Comment: the use the charatcers not number substitution. and also try using lstm/gru layers. this looks like a sequence to sequence problem.

Comment: okay i'll try using LSTM but I can't use string characters cos the model doesn't accept string, also converting it to a simple consonant/vowel relationship helps the model learn the pattern more easily

Comment: @aSaffary just asking, looking at the code, is there anything wrong with the code I posted?

Comment: the overall code looks ok. I would try to use my own preprocessing to convert chars instead of keras embedding layer. just convert each char to its one-hot encoded vector ( count whitespace as a char too). use lstm as layers and for prediction maybe timedistributed dense layers with size of two to indicate which  char is beginning of a new syllable. you will need to create a good deal of training data thou.

Comment: there might be a much easier/better way to do it and I wouldn't know because I've never read about this problem. I'm just trying to solve it your way. do more reading before implementing anything I said.